Ubuntu 20.04 unexpectedly crash everytime
I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 for a year. Now I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed in a new system, but it crashes unexpectedly. Terminal is not open and facing many issues and errors.
Can someone tell me the stable release of Ubuntu 20.04 or why I am facing these issues?
Thanks

the current version of Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ suggest download the desktop .iso file image and re-install. You have a copy of the data from your old system, right?
